# Viewwillappear called but viewdidappear not called

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

the viewwillappear is called in my viewcontroller but for some reason the viewdidappear is not called.

I am showing the view by calling the navigatorcontroller push method.

Comment: what you have written in viewWillAppear? can you post some portion of your code

Comment: Just initialising a couple of views. Even if I empty the viewdidappear, it still doesn't get called.

Comment: in above comment did you mean viewWillappear right?

Comment: ye so essentially the first one is called but viewdidappear doesn't get called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encountered this problem on ios5 system and guessed apple change the view invoke method.

Maybe you can try to write the same code in both viewwillappear and viewdidappear.